# gtags produces empty GTAGS file with pygments

Tags: emacs, global, gnu, ctags, pygments

I am trying to run gtags on a python code base with a pygments plug-in parser, but the GTAGS file produced is empty and the GRTAGS references stuff like "str" which just seems wrong to me.

Here are relevant parts of the .globalrc:

```
default:\
    :tc=native:tc=pygments:
pygments:\
    :tc=pygments-parser:tc=htags:
```

and pygments-parser is pretty straightforward, I guess.
Global is version 6.6.2. I have read this might be a problem with ctags, which pygment uses for definition tags, however gtags --explain does not mention any usage of ctags - should it?
The .globalrc does not specify any configuration of ctags, but judging by the pygments plug-in manual this should not be necessary as pygments uses it internally. Is that correct?
What could be the cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also use `global (GNU GLOBAL) 6.6.2`.  I don't have my own
`.globalrc`.  The following method described in
`/usr/share/gtags/PLUGIN_HOWTO.pygments` works for me:

```
$ export GTAGSCONF=/usr/share/gtags/gtags.conf
$ export GTAGSLABEL=pygments
$ gtags
$ ls -Al G*
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users  32768 May 28 22:22 GPATH
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 458752 May 28 22:22 GRTAGS
-rw-r--r-- 1 ja users 253952 May 28 22:22 GTAGS
```

After doing that I can use [gtags
mode](https://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2009/01/navigating-through-source-code-using.html)
inside `Emacs` to jump to a function definition and calls.

***EDIT***: I checked that in order for this to work I need to have a working `ctags` binary in my `$PATH`, it's also described in the help file I mentioned:

```
Make sure python and ctags can be invoked in your command line.
$ type python
python is /usr/bin/python
$ type ctags
ctags is /usr/local/bin/ctags
```

Comment: This does not change anything.
I have just written a hello.py file with a def message() in it, and after running gtags with either the default config you proposed or my .globalrc there is no entry in GTAGS, only in GRTAGS - the same behaviour as on any arbitrary code base so far.

I also do have ctags in $PATH and I actually have read the FAQ, HOWTOs and the github-manual on the pyments plug-in.

So you're saying everything just worked out of the box for you?
Did you install pygments via pip? Am asking because the manual states that pygments comes bundled with global these days.

Comment: Yes, it worked out of the box. No, I didn't install pygments via pip.

Comment: ... but via my operating system package manager. If `pygments` module is not installed `gtags` complains: `ImportError: No module named pygments.lexers`. I forgot I ever installed it. What version of `Pygments` do you have? Here I have `2.1.3`.

Comment: The problem was indeed with ctags, but in some ways more precisely with apt: my ctags was not exuberant, although apt insisted it was, and pygments failed on the missing --filter option.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue:

1. `Gtags` couldn't recognize programming languages other than the ones it has basic support for, including .py and .vim, among others.
2. When I set `--gtagslabel` to `pygments`, it generated an empty `GTAGS` file.

Check the `EXUBERANT_CTAGS` path in `pygments_parser.py` and ensure that `ctags` is exactly located there.